Apache web server port redirection
I know this is not the first posted question on this topic, but I was hoping to find someone to help me better understand if there are possible solutions to the problem. Also, I wanted to start being more active on Stack Overflow :D
On my Windows 10 virtual machine I installed an Apache 2.4 web server with listen option in the httpd.conf file set to
Listen 81

This is because port 80 is already used by SYSTEM services I don't think I can stop. I believe the culprit is a virtual desktop agent:
C:\Users\my_username>netsh http show servicestate | findstr ":80"
HTTP://+:80/CITRIX/VIRTUALDESKTOPAGENT/ILAUNCH/
HTTP://+:80/CITRIX/VIRTUALDESKTOPAGENT/IDYNAMICDATAQUERY/
HTTP://+:80/CITRIX/VIRTUALDESKTOPAGENT/ICONFIGURATION/
HTTP://+:80/CITRIX/VIRTUALDESKTOPAGENT/ISESSIONMANAGER/
HTTP://+:80/CITRIX/VIRTUALDESKTOPAGENT/IQUERYAGENT/

I was hoping to automatically redirect browser http requests coming at my_hostname.my_domain (and hence equivalently at my_hostname.my_domain:80 ?) to the actual Apache server my_hostname.my_domain:81,.
My question: is my attempt useless because port 80 is already used by other services? If not, what could be an effective solution?
Here a few attempts:
Attempt1: I started editing the C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf file like this:
Listen 81
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName my_hostname.my_domain
    ServerAlias my_hostname
    DocumentRoot c:/Apache24/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName my_hostname.my_domain
    ServerAlias my_hostname
    Redirect permanent / my_hostname.my_domain:81
</VirtualHost>

Attempt2: I removed the virtual hosts, uncommented the line
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

and added the lines
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}:81$1 [R=301,L]

Attempt3: I uncommented the lines
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so

and added the lines
ProxyPass / http://my_hostname.my_domain:81/
ProxyPassReverse / http://my_hostname.my_domain:81/

Future attempts: try to put reverse proxy option in a virtualhost block? maybe as an intermediate step try to do this on my physical Windows 10 machine which has not other services on port 80.
